# Is this proof for "If $2x+y$ is odd then x is odd or y is odd." sufficient.

Tags: logic, proof-verification

My proof:
Consider the contrapositive: "If x and y and both even, then 2x+y is even.
2x+y = even*even + even = even. The contrapositive is logically equivalent, hence the statement is true.

Comment: The "stronger" statement *"If $2x+y$ is odd then $y$ is odd."* is true as well.

Comment: You may want to correct the "even*even + even = even" part into something more mathematically correct though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You could also argue directly: If $2x + y$ is
odd then $2x + y = 2k + 1$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$. It follows that
$y = 2(k-x) + 1$ is odd. Therefore
$$ 
 \text{$2x+y$ is odd} \Longrightarrow \text{$y$ is odd}
 \Longrightarrow \text{$x$ is odd or $y$ is odd}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the proof is perfectly correct. If you'd like to write it a little bit more formally, you could say:

Suppose that both $x$ and $y$ are even. Then there exist $m,n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $x=2m$ and $y=2n$ and therefore, $2x + y = 4m + 2n = 2(2m+n)$ which is even since $2m + n \in \Bbb{Z}$.

But the logical steps are perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Looks right might want to fix some typos though. Note it's sufficient to show that if y is even then 2x+y is even.